# Can I pass the params from controller to service class

Tags: grails, groovy

In `studentRegister` controller interface

```
def save() {
    def studentRegister=studentRegisterService.serviceRegisterSave(params)
}
```

In `studentRegisterService` class

```
def serviceRegisterSave(params){
    // get the params and do operation
}
```

Can I receive the params from controller interface to service class? How can I pass that which scope?

Comment: I get the params from request in controller 's save method. Then I have to implement the business logic in service class . So can I pass the params to Service class 's metho like above my code.

Comment: thank you . Because this business layer only I can't run.So I could not guess what the result is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsParameterMap

class StudentRegisterService {

    def serviceRegisterSave(GrailsParameterMap params){
        // get the params and do operation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can pass params which is in request scope. In grails 2.2.1 I have done this in MyController.

```
def flag = myService.saveSomething(params)
```

And in MyService.

```
def saveSomething(params){
}
```

As param map is provided by grails through request object. [Refer docs](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Controllers/params.html)

But should you do that? No. Its not a good practice to pass params in service

Extracting your required values from params in your controller and then pass them in your service is recommended

Refer [this docs](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/services.html)

Comment: the links are broken for me. Substituting the version for `latest` returns valid up-to-date documentation http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Controllers/params.html, http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/services.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
//in controller same as yours
 def save() {
 def studentRegister=studentRegisterService.serviceRegisterSave(params)
 }
 //change your service as below given
 def serviceRegisterSave = { params ->
 // get the params and do operation
 }
```